# Cooking book online.. can I use Springtool and Java?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am learning at work how to use **SpringTool, Roo, Hibernate, MySQL** but I would like to improve a bit. I always wanted to do an online cooking book where people can contribute with their recipes. The idea is to have tags for the ingridients, difficulty and body of the recipe and allow the registered user to submit those.

The server should be able to generate a PDF document using Latex. A first step would be including all the submitted recipes. Another one would be to select which recipes the user wants and then produce the PDF containing only those.

Does anyone know if I can use the tools above? Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Regards

Comment: LaTeX?  Are you planning to do a lot of mathematics typesetting?  That's what LaTeX is best suited for.

Comment: Those tools will be just fine, I'm not so sure about the LaTeX choice though.  There are simpler Java friendly PDF generators out there.  As duffymo says, you probably don't need the mathematical support of LaTeX.

Comment: @duffymo I am not planning to do maths settings but I considered that LaTeX was a good choice for the following: 1-I could divide the document in chapters and sections and then generate automatically a ps file out of them. 2-LaTeX supports very well also indexing and usually the final result is quiet nice in terms of aspect. I am a bit new to webdevelopment so I am not aware of the new tools for that. So Liferary will help for generating documents in the way I want?

Comment: Liferay is a portal.  I'm not aware that it'll help you with this problem, but I'm not a Liferay expert.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a CMS you want to build on. Have a look at [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) which purely build in java and mostly relies on the frameworks you want out of the box like Spring, Hibernate and MySQL. Then you can build your application as a portlet i.e. [eclipse](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Eclipse+Plugin). Not sure about the LaTeX integration though.